# Dividing a number into groups of numbers

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, range

I have an algorithm that generates a range of numbers. The parameters are `$min`, `$range`. If I give the values:

```
$min = 4
$range = 1
```

The algorithm generates the numbers, that can be grouped in the minimum to the maximum range. Say, for the above inputs, the algorithm generates the numbers starting from `$min`, `$min + $range`, multiplied by the increments:

```
Iteration n: range($min x n to ($min + 1) x n)
Iteration 1: 4, 5            // range (4, 5)
Iteration 2: 8, 9, 10        // range (8, 10) 
Iteration 3: 12, 13, 14, 15  // range (12, 15) 
// and so on!
```

So, if I give the input number as `13`, we can understand that it can be obtained by any of the ways:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1
3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 1
4 + 4 + 4 + 1
5 + 5 + 3
6 + 6 + 1
7 + 6
8 + 5
```

And so on. But based on the inputs, we have numbers only in the range `4` and `5`. So, I should get the answer:

```
4 + 4 + 5
```

If I go by the above method, of starting with bigger numbers, it will iterate by:

```
5 + 5 + 3     // 3 is Invalid
4 + 4 + 4 + 1 // 1 is Invalid
```

How to make the algorithm understand that the common match or something like Highest Common Factor or Greatest Common Divider concept, we need to get only the following result:

```
4 + 4 + 5
```

I am stuck with this, on how to proceed. The above explanation is the implementation of the algorithm, but I have no clue how to implement it.

One of the try that I have is, making a mix of all the numbers and try to flag off each bit. So, at the first attempt, I am taking the smallest number to match it with the least:

```
4 + 4 + 4
```

As, `4 + 4 + 4 + 4` exceeds `13`. Now, am taking the next guy:

```
5 + 5 + 5
```

And keeping the two sets of inputs, I am reducing the number one by one:

```
Try 0: 5 + 5 + 5 // Larger
Try 1: 5 + 5 + 4 // Larger
Try 2: 5 + 4 + 4 // Success
```

---

#### Update #1

Current implementation is:

```
function getNums($k, $range, $num)
{
    $q = floor($num / $k);
    $r = $num % $k;
    echo str_repeat($q . ", ", $k - $r), str_repeat(($q+1) . ", ", $r);
}
```

The output is bizarre:

```
getNums(4, 1, 13); // 3, 3, 3, 4 // Expecting 4, 4, 5
getNums(4, 1, 18); // 4, 4, 5, 5
```

Comment: The naive approach is to try every combination of numbers within the specified range.  Some input numbers and ranges will not have a result.  **Hint:** Your final solution will probably be recursive.

Comment: If `$min` were `4` and `$range` were `2`, which subset of `10 == 4 + 6` and `10 == 5 + 5` and `10 == 6 + 4` would you want?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Nice question... :) No idea as I haven't thought about it since I am working with the `$range` with values either `0` or `1`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I would take a random or the one with equal weight! :)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Tried your way, I am not getting it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split `n` as evenly as possible `k` ways: compute `q = n / k` and `r = n % k` (floor division/modulo). Return a `k`-element list containing `k - r` copies of `q` and `r` copies of `q + 1`. Both `q` and `q + 1` (if used) will be in range.

```
function getNums($q, $range, $num)
{
    $k = floor($num / $q);
    $r = $num % $q;
    echo str_repeat($q . ", ", $k - $r), str_repeat(($q+1) . ", ", $r);
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. Trying it out. Will keep you updated!

Comment: Tried it, and it went on an infinite loop! `:(`

Comment: Can you please check out the implementation of your suggestion? I am not getting it right!

Comment: @PraveenKumar We were using `k` to mean different things. See my edit for a corrected version of your code.

Comment: This is not good for high numbers.output for 720 144, 144, 144, 144, 144,